# RabbitMQ not receiving messages when used with TopShelf as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, rabbitmq

I'm trying to convert my RabbitMQ micro-service to a windows service.  I have used TopShelf for the conversion.  My RabbitMQ micro-service works perfectly fine on its own but when I run it as a service it no longer receives messages.  In my `public static void Main(string[] args)` I have:

```
 HostFactory.Run(host =>
                {
                    host.Service<PersonService>(s =>                      
                    {
                        s.ConstructUsing(name => new PersonService());
                        s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());             
                        s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());               
                    });
                    host.SetDescription("Windows service that provides database access totables."); 
                    host.SetDisplayName("Service");                   
                    host.SetServiceName("Service");
                });
            }
```

Then in my `PersonService` class I have

```
public void Start() {
            ConsumeMessage();
        }
```

And finally my `ConsumeMessage` function:

```
private static void ConsumeMessage() {
        MessagingConfig.SetInstance(new MessagingConstants());
        IMessageFactory pmfInst = MessageFactory.Instance;

        //message worker
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() {
            HostName = MessagingConfig.Instance.GetBrokerHostName(),
            UserName = MessagingConfig.Instance.GetBrokerUserName(),
            Password = MessagingConfig.Instance.GetBrokerPassword()
        };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: MessagingConfig.Instance.GetServiceQueueName(),
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: MessagingConfig.Instance.GetServiceQueueName(),
                                 noAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine("Service.");
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests");


            // Code Below Is Not Executed In Service
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {

                string response = null;

                var body = ea.Body;
                var props = ea.BasicProperties;
                var replyProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                replyProps.CorrelationId = props.CorrelationId;

                string receivedMessage = null;

                try {
                    receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    response = ProcessMessage(receivedMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // Received message is not valid.
                    WinLogger.Log.Error(
                        "Errror Processing Message: " + receivedMessage + " :" + e.Message);

                    response = "";
                }
                finally {

                    var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: props.ReplyTo,
                    basicProperties: replyProps, body: responseBytes);
                    channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag,
                    multiple: false);
                }
            };
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Looking at [A similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702564/rabbitmq-consumer-as-a-windows-service/37865550#37865550?newreg=00862ca04c0b4869bfa3f430137ea0c3) it looks like it has something to do with the return the Windows Service is wanting, but I'm not sure of how to call `ConsumeMessage` so `consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {...};` is executed.

**EDIT:** It looks like my blocking mechanism  `Console.ReadLine();` is ignored by the service so it just continues on and disposes of the message consumer.  So how do I block there for messages to be received?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You code uses `using` construct, which means when your `OnStart` method returns, your `channel` will actually be disposed. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) suggest to do your initialization on `OnStart`, so create your `channel` and `consumer` there, but don't use `using`:

```
this.connection = factory.CreateConnection();

this.channel = connection.CreateModel();
this.consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(this.channel);
```

Then those objects will continue to exist after `OnStart` method is finished. You should dispose of them in the `OnStop` method.

Comment: Since I'm using Topshelf I have `tc => tc.Start();` as noted above, which I assume is the same as `OnStart`?  So If I understand you correctly, 1. make connection, channel, and consumer class members, 2. initialize in Start(), then in `ConsumeMessage` keep `consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {...}` the way it is? What is stopping `ConsumeMessage` from finishing and taking  `consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {...}` out of scope?

Comment: yes, your problem is really in the `using` statement - after your code passes  its curly bracket just before `Console.ReadLine()` your channel is disposed and you won't have any messages

Comment: So I made class members `private IConnection connection; private EventingBasicConsumer consumer; private IModel channel;` moved initialization to `Start()` and removed `using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) {` When I execute it as command line app my results return but if I run it as a service not it returns 404, so it somewhat fixed the problem, let me try again tomorrow to see if I can fix it and accept your answer

Comment: To allow the windows service access to the DB I had to go to properties for the service, Log On, and choose This Account and enter my credentials